# Mixed PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and Spring bean with type java.util.properties

Tags: java, spring

I have these configuration below on my application context xml

```
  <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:jmsconfig.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsConfigPropertyPlaceHolder" class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">           
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
                    <constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['SHARED_DIR']}/messaging/broker.properties" />
                </bean>         
            </list>
        </property>    
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsProperties" class="java.util.Properties">
        <constructor-arg>
            <props>
                <prop key="transportURI">${transportURI}</prop>
                <prop key="maxConcurrentConsumers">${maxConcurrentConsumers}</prop>
                <prop key="timeToLive">${timeToLive}</prop>
                <prop key="cacheConsumer">${cacheConsumer}</prop>
                <prop key="cacheProducer">${cacheProducer}</prop>
                <prop key="deliveryPersistent">${deliveryPersistent}</prop>
            </props>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

I got the below exception when loading my context

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#0'
>   defined in class path resource [dbaccessContext.xml]: Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through bean property 'properties': : **No
>   qualifying bean of type [java.util.Properties] is defined: expected
>   single matching bean but found 2:
>   jmsProperties,systemProperties**; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [java.util.Properties] is defined: expected
>   single matching bean but found 3:
>   jmsProperties,systemProperties

Appreciate for any help on this.

Updated.

I found the root cause that make my context failed to load, because my context had: default-autowire="byType" so Spring will try to inject all my spring property by type.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd"
    **default-autowire="byType"**>
```

After removing **default-autowire="byType"**, my app work now.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the exception message more carefully it already tells you `com.alu.ov.ngnms.properties.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#0` which is not a Spring class, has a `properties` field which is being injected.

Unfortunately, the code did not anticipate there could be more than one `Properties` bean in the application context. You'll have to modify that (anoymous inner) class and explicitly specify the `Properties` bean it was originally expecting by name (either with `@Named` or `@Resource` depending on your code convention).

Comment: This is my typo, I updated it. There is only context that my code refer to dbaccessContext.xml